# Using a custom sink with ServiceStack.Logging.Serilog?

Tags: servicestack, serilog

Is there a non-obvious way (to me at least) to add a custom sink e.g. MongoDB or MicrosoftTeams as part of instantiating the Serilog factory in the ServiceStack framework or will it be a case of rolling your own factory and implementation of ILog?

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Logging.Serilog

LogManager.LogFactory =  new SerilogFactory();
```

[ServiceStack Logging](http://docs.servicestack.net/logging)

[Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started)

[Example: MongoDB Sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mongodb)

This works without using the ServiceStack implementation, but is it considered bad form?

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.MongoDBCapped("mongodb://mymongourl:27017/mylogs",
            collectionName: "mycollectionoflogs", cappedMaxSizeMb: 50,
            cappedMaxDocuments: 10000)
        .CreateLogger();

    SetConfig(new HostConfig
    {
        DefaultRedirectPath = "/metadata",
        DebugMode = AppSettings.Get(nameof(HostConfig.DebugMode), false)              
    });
}
```

and in the ServiceInterface message implementation:

```
public object Any(MyRequest request)
{
    Log.Information("I'm a lumberjack and I'm OK");

    return new MyRequestResponse
    {
        Result = $"{ results.Chop() }"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just added a constructor overload to use a custom Serilog logger in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/4c8701a22972192cda3e6119d9d58e8b8ba6ce89), this change is available from v5.1.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

With this change you can pass a custom Serilog logger with ServiceStack's `SerilogFactory`, e.g:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new SerilogFactory(new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.MongoDBCapped("mongodb://mymongourl:27017/mylogs",
        collectionName: "mycollectionoflogs", cappedMaxSizeMb: 50,
        cappedMaxDocuments: 10000)
    .CreateLogger());
```

You can use the Serilog logger directly like in your example except it wont be able to capture ServiceStack's built-in logs or be able to substitute it later with any of the other [ServiceStack loggers](http://docs.servicestack.net/logging).

Comment: Thanks [@mythz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz), much appreciated.  Will pull from MyGet